# Remote Desktop into a non-technical family member's PC

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access

My parents use several PCs (desktops/laptops running Windows 7) in the house. They are not tech-savvy. I'm the administrator on their PCs, and they are standard users. I do maintenance every so often, such as run Windows Update and update various programs when I am at home.

I will be moving out of the house soon and would like to be able to remote-desktop into their PCs from outside the home network, from my Mac (or even Windows VM via [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/)).

How can I do so with the following restrictions:

1. The WAN **IP address is dynamic**.
2. The members of the household **do not need to figure out any IP address whatsoever**. All they need to know how to do, is ensure that the PCs/router/cable-modem are all turned on.
3. It should be a **secure connection**.
4. The members of the household **do not need to be present in front of the PC** for me to remote into it.

What options are there for this? How can I set this up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The WAN IP address is dynamic.

Use a dynamic DNS (DDNS) service like [Dyn](http://dyn.com/dns/) or [No-IP](http://www.no-ip.com/). By installing a client or configuring a DDNS-enabled modem/router, the WAN IP can be periodically updated to a domain name.

> The members of the household do not need to figure out any IP address whatsoever. All they need to know how to do, is ensure that the PCs/router/cable-modem are all turned on.

Solved with DDNS.

> It should be a secure connection.

Other than Microsoft's own Remote Desktop Connection, [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/) is a popular solution for screen-sharing and remote desktop. It uses AES256 for encryption and RSA private/public key exchange. More [here](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/products/security.aspx). Additionally, there is no need for DDNS because IDs are used to initiate sessions. Extracted from the TeamViewer manual [[PDF](http://www.teamviewer.com/download/teamviewer_manual.pdf)], these are the steps for remote support.

[image]

There are also various VNC solutions, but VNC is [not a secure protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing#Security) by itself, and needs to be paired with SSH or VPN for additional security.

> The members of the household do not need to be present in front of the PC for me to remote into it.

For TeamViewer, you will have to do some [initial configurations](http://www.viaarena.com/teamviewer-remote-connection-pc-to-pc.aspx?ID=107&MCatID=1&P=2) for unattended access. After that, they just need to power the computers on :)

[image]